# try-with-resources JDBC Pool Timeout: Pool empty. чтож так

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pool

Всем привет. Написал я слой DAO JDBC, так криво как может написать эго новичок.
Узнал я про try-with-resources и подумал использовать его.
Очень сократил код. И тесты проходили.
Но когда переписал весь слой, запустил тесты, и все пипец.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [main] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:30; busy:30; idle:0; lastwait:10000].
```

Вылетает после некоторого количество успешных тестов. Первая мысль, что try-with-resources не отдает в пул соединение. Но не пойму почему. По гуглу нашел подобные вопросы, но языковой барьер или усталость не дает понять, что такое случилось у меня )) ткните носом плиз.

Вот пример кода:

```
    public Person takeBy(Integer id) throws SQLException {
    Person person = null;
    try (PreparedStatement statement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from persons where id=?")) {
        statement.setInt(1, id);
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                person = new Person(id, rs.getString("name"));
            }
        }
    }
    if (person == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Person not found.");
    }
    return person;
}
```

Настройки пула:

```
private static DataSource getDataSourceReal() {
    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8809/base?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow");
    p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    p.setUsername("name");
    p.setPassword("12345678");
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(30);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(5);
    p.setMaxIdle(30);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
                    "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
    DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
    return datasource;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Первая мысль, что try-with-resources не отдает в пул соединение.

Истина где-то рядом.

У тебя

```java
try (PreparedStatement statement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from persons where id=?"))
{
//...
}
```

А должно быть

```java
try(Connection con=dataSource.getConnection()){
   try (PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from persons where id=?"))
   {
   //...
   }
}
```

Можно то же, но в один try-with-resource

```java
try(Connection con=dataSource.getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from persons where id=?")){
   //...
}
```

Иными словами, ты закрывал `PreparedStatement`, но не закрывал `Connection`.

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное. Ты спас мне много времени)) ошибка новичка...